# ggkf.com duplicate a lot of content from Stack Overflow, with apparently no respect of the CC licence

Tags: discussion

Today, on the page [w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic/), I found a line like this:

> Pingback: DOMDocument::validate() problem - PHP Solutions - Developers Q & A

linking to the site http://www.ggkf.com/php/domdocument-appendxml-with-special-characters.

This is a duplicate of my question on Stack Overflow: [DOMDocument::validate() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062792/domdocumentvalidate-problem) but I can find no mention of my name, nor to Stack Overflow, and answers to the question aren't here either, so, they are referencing problems without solutions already provided.

Is this normal?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers

Comment: These domain names just get more and more original! I won't be happy until asdfghjkl.com copies all of our content too. People that make these things should be barred from using the Internet, period.